# Efficient table comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that there are the following ways to select values present in one table but not in other.

```
LEFT JOIN, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS
```

Which is the recommended option to use?

There probably isn't an universal answer - so would appreciate the used-case where each is advisable.

(I am not looking for the syntax of the above options - just a comparison of the approaches)

Comment: are you looking for outer join?
this will return all values that are in table x or table y that arent in both

Comment: No.I am looking at the recommended option from the above filtering 'present in left but not in right'

Comment: @IUnknown - If you are satisfied with any of the answer, then accept it so the question could be closed. Else mention what else you looking from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `LEFT JOIN` takes *slightly* more time that other two. But `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` took almost same time.

I prefer `left join` when I need to utilize the values of `other` table in select clause. Else I prefer `not exists`.

I suggest you to replicate the below test on your machine as mine is a home machine with `Oracle 12c` and hardly anything else running. May be in a bigger environment, the test will give more accurate result.

**Test in detail:**

To practically test it I will create 2 tables and insert first one with 10 Million rows and second one with some other condition from first one, so some rows are not inserted to second table.

```
--Create first table
create  table test_data_left (empno integer, ename varchar2(10),CONSTRAINT tdl_pk primary key(empno));

--PLSQL Block to enter 10 Million rows in test_data_left
declare v_max_empno integer;
BEGIN
select coalesce(max(EMPNO),0) into v_max_empno from  emp_data;
  FOR i IN 1..1000000 LOOP  -- add 10 Million rows
   insert into test_data_left(empno,ename) values (
   i+v_max_empno,
    DBMS_RANDOM.string('U',TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(10,11)))
  );   
  END LOOP;
END;
/
commit;

--Create second table and populate with some condition to block some rows from first table

create  table test_data_right (empno integer, ename varchar2(10),CONSTRAINT tdr_pk primary key(empno));

insert into  test_data_right (empno,ename)
select empno,ename from test_data_left
where ename not like 'JK%';
```

These are the queries I am using to get the data. 
NOTE: I am not using `t1.*` in select statements, as SQL Developer only displays first 50 rows and you cannot run explain plan on it. Hence I am using `count(*)`

```
select count(*)  from test_data_left t1 left join test_data_right t2 on 
t1.empno=t2.empno where t2.empno is nulll

select count(*) from test_data_left t1
where t1.empno not in (select empno from test_data_right);

select count(*) from test_data_left t1
where not exists (select 1 from test_data_right t2 where t1.empno=t2.empno);
```

To gather status of last run query, I used this command.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST')) ;
```

Just to be careful, that Oracle is not doing any funny business while calculating, I had reset the database connection before running every query.

Below are the status after each query. I have repeated it in reverse order to give a fair chance to `LEFT JOIN`.

> As far as I can see, the `LEFT JOIN` is the slowest but `NOT IN` and
>   `NOT EXISTS` are almost same. (based on couple of more iterations which I wasn't able to capture)

**Iteration 1**

LEFT JOIN

```
SQL_ID  0qz2qtza4yrr0, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*)  from test_data_left t1 left join test_data_right t2 on 
t1.empno=t2.empno where t2.empno is null

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.41 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.41 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.32 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.22 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.54 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="T2"."EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

NOT EXISTS

```
SQL_ID  c498qdbzw5dxv, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*) from test_data_left t1 where not exists (select 1 from 
test_data_right t2    where t1.empno=t2.empno)

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.27 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.27 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.19 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.21 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.49 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="T2"."EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

NOT IN

```
SQL_ID  gwm775xqnufgm, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*) from test_data_left t1 where t1.empno not in (select 
empno from test_data_right)

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.23 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.23 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.15 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.19 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.47 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

**ITERATION 2**

NOT IN

```
SQL_ID  gwm775xqnufgm, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*) from test_data_left t1 where t1.empno not in (select 
empno from test_data_right)

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.19 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.19 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.11 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.19 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.46 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

NOT EXISTS

```
SQL_ID  c498qdbzw5dxv, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*) from test_data_left t1 where not exists (select 1 from 
test_data_right t2    where t1.empno=t2.empno)

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.19 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.19 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.12 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.19 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.46 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="T2"."EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

LEFT JOIN

```
SQL_ID  0qz2qtza4yrr0, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select count(*)  from test_data_left t1 left join test_data_right t2 on 
t1.empno=t2.empno where t2.empno is null

Plan hash value: 2082679279

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:01.33 |    5012 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:01.33 |    5012 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI    |        |      1 |   1206K|    900K|00:00:01.24 |    5012 |
|   3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TDL_PK |      1 |   1206K|   1000K|00:00:00.22 |    1891 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN   | TDR_PK |   1000K|      1 |  99865 |00:00:00.50 |    3121 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."EMPNO"="T2"."EMPNO")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

this will return everything from table a where there is not corresponding record in table b

```
SELECT a.col FROM a WHERE a.col NOT IN (SELECT b.col from b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try on below query

```
select tabA.* from tabA left join tabB on tabA.id = tabB.tabA_id
where tabB.tabA_id is null
```

Hope it can help.